# How do you select a column with Japanese characters?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select a column in SQL that contains Japanese character. The output of the Japanese characters are converted into ????? (question marks).

Please advice.

Comment: I admit, I know little about MySQL. But I'm going to guess you need to select one char at a time (increment up) and search through the database. First look at U-3040 to U-30FF (Hiragana to Katakana) then U-4E00 to U-9FAF (Kanji). Anyone want to solidify this idea? Also perhaps `dechex(hexdec('4e00') + 1)` to increment?

Comment: just got it solved myself,
put this line after your connect.php ///sql connect configuration
mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");

Comment: The price of asking on superuser is that you have to answer your own question if you resolve it yourself. Please write an answer on some details on how you solved your issue, (basically say what you just commented, but explain)

Answer (score 2):

After establishing connecting to the database, it is necessary that we change the character-set for accessing the SQL database by using:

```
mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");
```

The above line works only "in new PHP versions" according to the source below.

As it is explained [here](http://www.kanjidatabase.com/japanese_developer_tips.php) why:

> If the browser is set to display utf-8 and tries to display text from
>   your PHP source or database that isn't proper utf-8 you may get
>   something like ��� instead of the intended characters.